# Firebase: what is a FirDatabaseQuery object actually used for?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've found millions of examples and tutorials on how to obtain a FirDatabaseQuery object (or DatabaseQuery as its now been renamed to) using one of the query....() methods.

But not one of these examples then goes on to show what you can do with the query once you have obtained it. 
If you use one of the query methods to obtain a subset of the data as a DatabaseQuery, how do you actually access the set of data objects that it represents? 
If you can't, for example, iterate through the query results like you can iterate through a snapshot, then what is a DatabaseQuery actually used for then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the answer to this is easily found in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).

I think that in the Android version of the class it is explained pretty well:

> [The Query class (and its subclass, DatabaseReference) are used for reading data. Listeners are attached, and they will be triggered when the corresponding data changes.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query)

I can explain it in my own words and more practical like this:

You can use the [`DatabaseQuery`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DatabaseQuery) object like a [`DatabaseReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DatabaseReference) just with the limitation that only the `observe` functions work and none of the methods used to manipulate the value, i.e. `setValue()` etc., of the reference nor any methods related to other nodes, i.e. parent and child (`child()` etc.), exist.

*(I took the code from the docs, so please be free to optimize it/bring in your coding style)*

This is how you get data from a `DatabaseReference`:

```
var postRef: DatabaseReference!
postRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts")

refHandle = postRef.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
  let postDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]
  // ...
})
```

And this is how you get data from a `DatabaseQuery`:

```
// My top posts by number of stars
let myTopPostsQuery = (ref.child("user-
posts").child(getUid())).queryOrdered(byChild: "starCount")

refHandle = myTopPostsQuery.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
  let postDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]
  // ...
})
```

As you can see the second part remains the same, as I mentioned, so *in retrieving data* you handle a `DatabaseQuery` like a `DatabaseQuery`. But I have to agree with you on the point that the **iOS** especially **Swift** docs are not that well made, the explanations for the other languages are way clearer.

Comment: That documentation illustrates the op's question, it show how to instantiate a query, but then not how to get data out of the query once its instantiated. That is the question question being asked, how to iterate through and access the data within the query.

Comment: @Sausagedioxide Sorry for not delivering a good enough explanation in the first place, I just updated my answer to provide you with the necessary example and I think that that will solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks, SO won't  let me award the bounty yet, I have to wait an hour for some reason.

Comment: No problem on that. I am glad that I could help you, I think it is always nice to look at the other languages in Firebase, gives more insights, but also kinda shows that the docs are not that well made.